# jQuery Tokeninput / No results found

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autocomplete

I use jQuery Tokeninput (autocomplete text entry) but i can't display the results, only "Searching" appears. My code is:

```
<input type="text" id="demo-input-pre-populated" name="blah" />
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#demo-input-pre-populated").tokenInput("includes/jugadores_lista.php");
});
</script>
```

And my php

```
mysql_pconnect("host", "user", "pass") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("database") or die("Could not select database");

$query = sprintf("SELECT id, nombre from jugadores WHERE nombre LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));
$arr = array();
$rs = mysql_query($query);

while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
    $arr[] = $obj;
}

$json_response = json_encode($arr);

if($_GET["callback"]) {
    $json_response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . $json_response . ")";
}

echo $json_response;
```

Php returns:

```
[{"id":"2","nombre":"Jugador 1},{"id":"1","nombre":"Jugador 2"}]
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't get it to work =(
Thanks,

Comment: `[{"id":"2","nombre":"Jugador 1},{"id":"1","nombre":"Jugador 2"}]` That's a type right? it's actually `"Jugador 1" <--` with the closing quote at the end? Also, change `nombre` to `name`, as it may strictly require the `id:` and `name:` key's

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, I change "nombre" to "name" and now works !!!, Thank you very much I didn't know it was so important x_X

Answer (score 0):

The json response should contain `name` key in it as the tokenInput by defaults search for `name`.

There is a setting to change this `propertyToSearch`, if you need some other key to look for.
In your case, this will also work.

`$("#demo-input-pre-populated").tokenInput("includes/jugadores_lista.php", { propertyToSearch: 'nombre' });`